# org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found:

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hsqldb

I have installed HSQLDB and I am trying it to connect to the CUSTOMER table which is in PUBLIC schema.I have not created this table.

```
Here is my dev.properties
oracle.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:.
oracle.username=sa
oracle.password=
oracle.driverType=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;


@Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="LASTNAME")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="STREET")
private String street;
```

when i launch my spring boot application i get the following error

> org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found:
>   CUSTOMER

in the database i can see the cutomer table though in public schema

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB is case-sensitive by default. Check if the table name in the database is being created as you have it defined in your code ( uppercase CUSTOMER ).

Comment: i just queried 
SELECT * FROM CustoMer;

And it worked.Its something related to schema i suppose